# Building a dictionary from a three dimensional array with Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting, dictionary, multidimensional-array

I am currently having a problem to sort my 3d array data into different dictionaries based on the first column of the array. I want to check the first column of the array and make a dictionary with the names of the strings in it. I would also like to make a two dimensional array with the values on the same row. My data looks like like something like that:

```
allValues=[["str1","str1","str1","str1","str1","str1","str1","str2","str2","str2","str2","str2"],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]]
```

And my aim is:

```
allValuesDict = {'str1': [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]], 'str2': [[8,9,10,11,12], [8,9,10,11,12]]}
```

Comment: I see a 2D array.  'row' and 'column' swapped in description too.  Is the 'key' column(1st row) presorted, number of each unique compatible with a reqular array output? or will you want a 'ragged list/dict' sometimes

Comment: Did an answer below help? Feel free to accept an answer (green tick on left), or ask for clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby` and `zip`:

```
import itertools
allValues=[["str1","str1","str1","str1","str1","str1","str1","str2","str2","str2","str2","str2"],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]] 
main, *rest = allValues
grouped_data = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([[[a, [h for _, h in b]] for a, b in itertools.groupby(zip(main, i), key=lambda x:x[0])] for i in rest]))
final_grouping = {a:[i for _, i in b] for a, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(grouped_data, key=lambda x:x[0]), key=lambda x:x[0])}
```

Output:

```
{'str1': [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]], 'str2': [[8, 9, 10, 11, 12], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12]]}
```

Comment: No idea, but I dislike DV without explanation, so +1 from me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `collections.defaultdict` for an O(n) solution.

Note this is *very specific* to the data structure you currently have:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(lambda: [[], []])

for i, j, k in zip(*allValues):
    d[i][0].append(j)
    d[i][1].append(k)
```

If you need to convert to a regular `dict`:

```
res = dict(d)

print(res)

{'str1': [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]],
 'str2': [[8, 9, 10, 11, 12], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12]]}
```

Answer (score 1):

`zip` can translate your list into `[['str1',1,1],['str2',2,2],...]` which can make iterating easier:

```
allValues = [['str1','str1','str1','str1','str1','str1','str1','str2','str2','str2','str2','str2'],
             [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],
             [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]]

D = {}
for k,v1,v2 in zip(*allValues):
    if k in D:
        D[k][0].append(v1)
        D[k][1].append(v2)
    else:
        D[k] = [[v1],[v2]]

print D
```

Output:

```
{'str2': [[8, 9, 10, 11, 12], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12]], 'str1': [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]}
```

Using `defaultdict` can simplify this further:

```
from collections import defaultdict

allValues = [['str1','str1','str1','str1','str1','str1','str1','str2','str2','str2','str2','str2'],
             [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],
             [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]]

D = defaultdict(lambda:[[],[]])
for k,v1,v2 in zip(*allValues):
    D[k][0].append(v1)
    D[k][1].append(v2)

print D
print dict(D)  # If you don't want the final type to be defaultdict.
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x00000000070A5128>, {'str2': [[8, 9, 10, 11, 12], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12]], 'str1': [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]})
{'str2': [[8, 9, 10, 11, 12], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12]], 'str1': [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas is a good tool for this. It produces fairly readable code.

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> df = pd.DataFrame(allValues).T
>>> df
       0   1   2
0   str1   1   1
1   str1   2   2
2   str1   3   3
3   str1   4   4
4   str1   5   5
5   str1   6   6
6   str1   7   7
7   str2   8   8
8   str2   9   9
9   str2  10  10
10  str2  11  11
11  str2  12  12

>>> grouped = df.groupby(0)[[1,2]].apply(lambda l: list(zip(*pd.Series.tolist(l))))
>>> grouped
0
str1    [(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)]
str2          [(8, 9, 10, 11, 12), (8, 9, 10, 11, 12)]
dtype: object

>>> grouped.to_dict()
{'str1': [(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)], 'str2': [(8, 9, 10, 11, 12), (8, 9, 10, 11, 12)]}
```

Comment: I think, that is what I need. So I can easily plot the curves with mathplotlib. Can you just give me a brief explanation of the groupby function? I mean that line: 
    grouped = df.groupby(0)[[1,2]].apply(lambda l: list(zip(*pd.Series.tolist(l))))

I can't find a good example on the net!

Comment: The groupby is a little convoluted... basically, *group* `df` on column 0 (the first column) -- you can think of this splitting `df` into two separate dataframes, one for `str1` and the other for `str2`. Then, convert the rows in each to `Series` (you need a `pandas`-aware type here; `list` alone will not work), zip them to convert to columns, and convert the zip into a list, then combine back into one dataframe. Take this dataframe and convert it to a dict.

Comment: Ok, I think is a little bit to complicated for me yet. But thank you. Is there a way to got it to work with python 2.7. It seems that the tolist function is working (TypeError: unbound method tolist() must be called with Series instance as first
argument (got DataFrame instance instead))

Comment: If you really can't move to Python 3, then don't use a solution with pandas, as pandas is dropping support for Python 2.7 on Jan 1, 2019. But you really should not be using Python 2.7 anymore.